# Ajax get id of element where there are multiple links with elements

Tags: javascript, ajax

The following code is what I am currently using to try and give the posts ID to vote.php, however this currently returns [object Object]. How would I be able to pass the correct id when a link is clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        data: "id=" + $(this).attr("href", "id"), 
        url: "vote.php"
        });  
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" id="1"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="2"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="3"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to also change id="button" to class="button" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the ajax call to a click handler:

```
$(document).on("click","a",function(e){
    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"), 
    url: "vote.php"
    });
});
```

Comment: Wasn't optional, his anchors aren't loaded when he's running the script.

Comment: Indeed, and it's better than using $.ready() + $.fn.click() ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function vote(_obj) {    
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        data: "id=" + $(_obj).attr("href", "id"), 
        url: "vote.php"
        });  
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.vote').click(function() {
            vote(this);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="1" class="vote"><div>Like!</div></a>
<a id="2" class="vote"><div>Like!</div></a>
<a id="3" class="vote"><div>Like!</div></a>
```

Some notes:

1. Do not use multiple elements with the same ID on a page
2. Bind events only after your DOM is loaded and ready, i.e. on or after the domready event.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are assigning the href of the links to `"id"` which does not make a lot of sense... And you should use event handlers for clicks...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('a.likeBTN').click($.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                data: "id=" + $(this).attr("id"), 
                url: "vote.php"
        }))});  
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" class="likeBTN" id="1"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="likeBTN" id="2"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="likeBTN" id="3"><div id="button">Like!</div></a>
```