# Select and display content from external div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i tried to display external content `div` on select option. Here is example

```
    <select>
      <option value="http://www.indiansuperleague.com/atletico-de-kolkata/squad/midfielder-3986-arata-izumi-playerprofile">ARATA
IZUMI</option>
      <option value="http://www.indiansuperleague.com/atletico-de-kolkata/squad/midfielder-10724-borja-fernandez-playerprofile">BORJA
FERNANDEZ</option>
      <option value="http://www.indiansuperleague.com/atletico-de-kolkata/squad/midfielder-10249-clifford-rayes-miranda-playerprofile">CLIFFORD
RAYES
MIRANDA</option>
    </select>
    <div id="content-display"></div>
```

When select I want to display content inside `<div class="player-detailswrap">`. And first option as default.

Please Help

Comment: you want to open an iframe inside that div?

Comment: you said you tried. Show us what you have tried and where do you get stuck at please.

Comment: no. to fetch using jquery

Comment: jQuery('div#content-display').html("/img/loader.gif'\" />").load('http://example.com/1 #this');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the select change event:

1. **Get the selected option value.**
2. **Create an iframe with this value as src attribute.**
3. **And append it to your div.**

This is your way to go:

```js
function displayOption(select) {
  var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  frame.src = select.value;
  document.getElementById("content-display").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("content-display").appendChild(frame);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="displayOption(this)">
  <option value="http://example.com/1">Content 1</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/2">Content 2</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/3">content 3</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/4">Content 4</option>
</select>
<div id="content-display"></div>
```

**This is a jquery solution:**

```js
//This code will initialize the div content
//You can use an id with the select if you have many dropdowns in the page
var dropdown = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
$('#content-display').load(dropdown.options[0].value);

function displayOption(select) {
  $('#content-display').load(select.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select onchange="displayOption(this)">
  <option value="http://example.com/1">Content 1</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/2">Content 2</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com">content 3</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/4">Content 4</option>
</select>
<div id="content-display"></div>
```

**EDIT:**

To answer your question about loading a div content from the other page:

If you need to load an external div content, you can use:

```
function displayOption(select) {
      $('#content-display').load(select.value+" #other-page-div-id");
}
```

Comment: The Updated one works..Thanks. The Default (First Option)is not displaying. I need to select the other to display. How will i fix

Comment: @user81244 you need to set it by default, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks..you save me@chsdk

Answer (score 1):

You need change event for select, on which you get the html from selected option value url using jquery get method and then set returned html to required div:

```
var content_display = $('#content-display');
$('select').change(function(){
    $.get(this.value, function( pagehtml ) {
      content_display.html( pagehtml );
    });
});
```

Comment: @Rayon: thanks... finally someone noticed this :). Not sure why OP is not interested :/

Answer (score 1):

Hello there you can try this

```
$(select).on('change', function(){
  $(#content-display).text($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

(If you're comfortable with using jquery)

```
$("#select_id").on("input", function(e){
  $("#content-display").text($(this).val())
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhtLmqxx/) of it working. `on` works best for listening for events.

Comment: I may have misunderstood. Did you just want to display the link for the selected value or actually load the page that is the link?

Comment: @Luke It may be works with on `change` not on 'input'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your want to load content from url.Use Ajax, it's easily can load contents without page reload.

```js
var toggleContents = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleContent');

if (toggleContents) {

  for (var i = 0; i < toggleContents.length; i++) {
    toggleContents[i].addEventListener('change', changeContent, false);
  }

}

function changeContent() {
  var content = document.querySelector(this.dataset.content);
  if (content) {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url_id = '#main-content';

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        content.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", this.value + url_id, true);
    xhttp.send();


  }

}
```

```html
<select class='toggleContent' data-content='#content-display'>

  <option value="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript">Content 1</option>

  <option value="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics">Content 2</option>

  <option value="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays">content 3</option>

  <option value="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode">Content 4</option>
</select>

<div id="content-display"></div>
```

Comment: very close thanks..how can i display selected block by id like #main-header of that link instead of displaying the full page

Comment: @user81244. Check now.

Comment: It still display the full page. i wat it to display some part only like. div#main-header only from that url

Comment: @user81244 provide your real urls and ids then i can update my answer as you want

Comment: @user81244 check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010495/ajax-get-id-of-element-where-there-are-multiple-links-with-elements

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to do this you can use jQuery AJAX GET or load request and simply feed the selector of the content you want form the page. The only thing is you HAVE to be on the same domain because of Cross Domain Policy.

You can take a look at [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in docs

```
$(document).load('test.html #container', fucn...) // Returns #container
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's [the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/rtbpnws8/2/)

```
$('#content').change(function() {
    $('#content-display').html($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I hope your problem will resolve, Please use the below code. Please vote for me if my answer right for your question.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlOption').change(function () {
var val=$("#ddlOption").val();
$("#content-display").html('');
   $("#content-display").append(val)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddlOption">
  <option value="http://example.com/1">Content 1</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/2">Content 2</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/3">content 3</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/4">Content 4</option>
</select>
<div id="content-display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in order to do this stuff more easy:

So, the content maybe can't be loaded because of **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**, this happens when you trying to access a URL you don't own or is reestricted.

Check the code here

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#select-content").change(function(){
      var content_url = jQuery("#select-content option:selected").val();
      if(content_url){
          jQuery("#content-display").load(content_url);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-content">
  <option value="">-- select content --</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/1">Content 1</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/2">Content 2</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/3">content 3</option>
  <option value="http://example.com/4">Content 4</option>
</select>
<div id="content-display"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to do like jQuery("#content-display").load('content_url #someid'); to load div id from this url

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be some simple jQuery functions. In this example, there are 4 divs with different content in each. All are hidden by default.

Then you can use a bit of jQuery to hide and show certain divs based on the selection you make:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.hidden').hide();
  $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value == 'defaultoption') {
        $('.hidden').hide();
      }
      else if (this.value == 'select1') {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $("#content1").show();
      }
      else if (this.value == 'select2') {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $("#content2").show();
      }
      else if (this.value == 'select3') {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $("#content3").show();
      }
      else if (this.value == 'select4') {
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $("#content4").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#content-display").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="defaultoption">Select Content</option>
  <option value="select1">Content 1</option>
  <option value="select2">Content 2</option>
  <option value="select3">Content 3</option>
  <option value="select4">Content 4</option>
</select>

<div id="content-display">
  <div id="content1" class="hidden">This is some text for content 1</div>
  <div id="content2" class="hidden">This is some text for content 2</div>
  <div id="content3" class="hidden">This is some text for content 3</div>
  <div id="content4" class="hidden">This is some text for content 4</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!